# Configurable Product MSRP

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sales-order, query

I'm working on a query where I need to grab the MSRP from a simple product for orders placed to run some finance calculations (margin...).

The `sales_flat_order_item` table includes the configurable product and the simple product with same skus, so it's same product but different data.

The configurable product in the table holds all the price values I need to generate a report, except for the custom attribute named cost which is only available through a join from the `catalog_product_flat_1` tables that is associated with the simple product.

I am currently filtering out the configurable products which means the order values wont be accessible for calculations.

Here is my current working query where `total_cost_sum` is null because of null MSRP value:

```
SELECT 
so.entity_id AS 'Header ID', si.item_id AS 'Item ID', si.product_type, so.increment_id, si.sku
, cf.msrp AS MSRP, cd.value AS 'Package Cost'
, sum(round((cf.msrp + cd.value + 7 + 7 + 7), 2)) AS total_cost_sum
, si.price AS 'Retail Price', si.price_incl_tax AS 'Retail Price Incl. Tax'
, so.discount_amount AS 'Discount Amount', so.grand_total AS 'Total Revenue', so.base_subtotal_incl_tax
FROM sales_flat_order AS so
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_item AS si ON si.order_id = so.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_flat_1 cf ON cf.entity_id = si.product_id # To get access to MSRP
JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal cd ON cd.attribute_id = 236 # Get access to Package Cost. Custom Attribute > package_cost defaults to 5
WHERE so.store_id = 1 # Store 1 Orders Only
AND si.product_type = 'configurable' # limit duplicates in calculation
GROUP BY so.entity_id
ORDER BY so.increment_id ASC, cf.msrp DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by performaing a left join 'LEFT JOIN catalog_product_flat_1 cf ON cf.sku = si.sku' on the product sku rather then product ID since I was using the configurable products ID's I wouldn't get access to the MSRP field.